# Can a plane with n punctures be considered a riemann surface?

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I have read a result saying that the fundamental group for a Riemann surface of genus n is a set of 2n generators $a_i, b_i$ such that $a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2... a_n b_n a_1 ^{-1}b_1 ^{-1}...a_n^{-1} b_n^{-1}=1$. However, this is not the case for the fundamental group of an n-punctured plane, whose fundamental group is just the free group. But it seems to me that the punctured plane is a Riemann surface, since I can construct the mapping $\Pi_i 1/(z-z_i)$, $z_i$ being the holes, from it to the complex numbers. What am I missing? Does this have to do with completing the plane with a point at infinity?

Thank you!

Comment: Your first two sentences are rather unclear. What distinction are you trying to make between a Riemann surface of genus $n$ and an $n$-punctured plane? In your phrase, "However, this is not the case..." what does the word "this" refer to?

Comment: Not a big mystery. By convention, the phrase "a Riemann surface of genus $n$" often implicitly means a surface without punctures. If one wants to be very clear, one would say "a *compact* Riemann surface of genus $n$". You are correct that the $n$-punctured plane is a Riemann surface (according to the usual definitions).

Comment: Example: the title of section 1.5 of Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces* is "The Genus of a Compact Riemann Surface". Some authors only define genus for compact surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

The standard definition of a Riemann surface is a connected second-countable Hausdorff space with a complex atlas. The $n$-punctured plane qualifies. To quote Farkas & Kra, *Riemann Surfaces*:

> We begin with a formal definition of a Riemann surface and give the simplest
> examples: the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, the extended complex plane or Riemann
> sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$, and finally *any open connected subset of a Riemann
> surface* [my emphasis].

Or Miranda, *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*:

> Example 1.21. Any connected open subset of a Riemann surface is a Riemann surface; use the atlas on the subset as described in Example 1.15.

The issue in the rest of your question is that the phrase "a Riemann surface of genus $n$" usually implicitly assumes that it's a compact Riemann surface. Some authors define *genus* only for the compact case. For example, a section heading in Miranda: "The Genus of a Compact Riemann Surface".